# Divide array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Welcome got fast question it's probably easy, but I'm stuck with it.

I've got an array in javascript, that looks like this:

```js
  var array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
```

Now I need to modify this array to look something like this:

```js
 var array = ['1:3', '4:5', '6:7'];
```

Is there elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the ways you tried, even if you think they lack elegance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var array = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i+=2) {
    newArray.push(array[i] + ':' + array[i + 1]);
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5jLzk/)

Comment: Of course, if array.length is odd, your last term will be something like '8:undefined', but that wasn't specced out in the OP.

Comment: Respectfully, it will be exactly like '8:undefined'.  This isn't c#... http://jsfiddle.net/5jLzk/1/

Comment: @ScottMermelstein you are entirely correct, my bad. Guess what I've spent most of today coding in :)

Comment: Just wrap the `for` loop in an if statement to avoid this trouble all together: `if((array.length % 2) == 0) { ... for loop ... }`.

Comment: Or you could do: `newArray.push(array[i] + ':' + (array[i + 1] || 0));` assuming the empty value should be coerced to zero.

Comment: Or `if (i + 1 <= array.length) { newArray.push...` to drop the odd element.  Or `for (var i = 0; i < (array.length % 2 == 1) ? array.length - 1 : array.length; i +=2) {` to accomplish the same purpose without adding an extra line...